# How to create an on/off switch and link it to mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I want a sliding switch. On the left would be Off and on the right would be On. When the user toggles the switch, a callback to the database would establish if the item linked to the button is still available (green light) or not (red light)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: There are millions of way you could connect a slide switch to a database query.

Comment: jquery - you can read about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/)

Comment: More specifically than jQuery: use AJAX. [With jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645602/how-to-use-ajax-with-jquery) and [without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery). Second link actually shows both with and without jQuery  in the answer