# Change content of div on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to php. I want to change the content of a div on click of a button which can be set to any other text.

```
<div id="container">
    <b>Dear ABC,</b>

    <p>Thank You for an order. Your order #" .$row['ordNum']."</p>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ord_id</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>.$row['order_id']."</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Thank You</p>
</div>
<input type="Button" value="change"/>
```

I want the user to update the message content above on button click. The order is not coming from db.

How will I allow the user to edit all of the text data except `orderId`?

Comment: You can use ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645602/how-to-use-ajax-with-jquery

Comment: please show your relevant code. It's not even clear if you want a php or a javascript solution

Comment: so all this is client side? remove the php tag and the php from the title IMHO

Comment: i updated the post with code..

Comment: @Gavriel This is a HTML page code.

Comment: @Gavriel The tags are all relevant. He wants to use ajax via javascript from a client in order to get data from a database via php on the server side. It's just not well stated.

Comment: but what are you asking for? to change the text in div#container when I click the input button? Then this is javascript only, no php. If so, remove php tag, 'cause it's confusing

Comment: I put php bcz i want php code to retrieve data from db too.

Comment: god, why prefix the question with [tag:php] and going completely different directions with the tags. Please fix your question, and get rid off the tags in the title!

Comment: @Freelancer, anyway, it's not clear IMHO, please try to edit the question to clarify it. It will also help if you include relevant parts of your existing php, js code, so we can see where to add the ajax

Comment: Basically what i am looking for is: Currently that msg text is static and i want to change that static text onclick of button. Am i suppose to store that text in db?

Comment: What you want and what you've done aren't clear. First, you ask how to change a div tag by pressing a button. This is a client side problem. Then you say that you want to get the order number from a database, which is done server side. After that you say that  you want to know how to edit the text, except for the order id. Based on all of this, I'm assuming that you want to press a button on the client side, get server side data, and inject it into your HTML. However, your php code prints the order id and number out so why would you want to send a request to the server to update one of them?

Comment: @DaveF No No....What i have in a Div is basically a email template(Ord_id will obviously come from database here). So far i have static email template in a Div with OrderId coming from database. Now i want to add a functionality wherein user(staff) can change the static text based on his need(OrderId will remains same as it come from db). So to change that text i have a button below div. When user(staff) clicks that button i want to allow him to change the static text. I have one way in my mind

Comment: i.e. i will open up a pop-up onclick of button, popup will contain one textarea in which i can load that template(I think i am suppose to it in db) and allow user to update and click save to save the content. Correct me if i am wrong or provide better option.

Answer (score 0):

you can request the content at a file in the same directory called xyz.php

with jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xyz.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        $('#container').html(data)
    }
})
```

the php file outputs some text

```
<?php

echo "<strong>yo</strong>";
```

maybe you get an idea

Comment: I strongly believe the OP has no inherent clue of (the difference between) server- and client-side. Your *hint* is honorable, but should rather be a comment as it does give no accurate solution to the problem described. That inital problem is also the reason why I am voting for a close - this question boils down to a tutorial, which is offtopic!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair i will never get the 7000

Comment: Not being a bounty/rep hunter and actually stick to the rules would easily get you there! ;)